# The most efficient way of finding indices of element(s) in numpy 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Out of huge matrix in numpy (currently `1000x1000`) only a few elements are relevant for me. Say these elements are `>1000` in value and others are way lower. I need to find indices of all such elements in the most efficient way because the search will be repeated often and the matrix can become even bigger.

For now I have two different approaches which should be about the same complexity (I omit possible solutions with `for` as inefficient):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((1000,1000))
#do something with the matrix

#first solution with np.where
np.where(A > 999).T
# array([[0, 0],[1, 20]....[785, 445]], dtype=int64) - made up numbers 

#another solution with np.argwhere
np.argwhere(A > 999)
# array([[0, 0],[1, 20]....[785, 445]], dtype=int64) - outputs the same
```

Is there any possible way to speed up this search or is my solution the most efficient?

Thanks for any advices and suggestion!

Comment: `argwhere` is `np.transpose(np.where(cond))`

Comment: so they are equivalent, thanks for clarification

Comment: `np.where(A > 999).T` - I'm surprised that this works.  `np.where` returns a tuple, and a tuple does not have a transpose method.  The argwhere approach first turns the tuple into an array.

Comment: Often the `where` tuple is more useful.  It can be used directly as index, `A[np.where(...)]`.  To use the `argwhere` result you have to iterate on rows (turning each into a tuple), or index with the 2 columns.  There's a good reason why `np.nonzero` returns a tuple of arrays rather than the 2d array.

Comment: What do you actually do with the indices once you have found them, please? A better optimisation may be possible if the next step in your processing can be  combined with this one....

Comment: @MarkSetchell the matrix represents a real map in abstract form, indices represent exact place convertable to lat/lon, the number in a column is equal to an event and we need to separate only one kind of events. Just to mention, the matrix is an output of a neural network. All I need to do is find the event locations and print them out, so this is actually a final step.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, the filter directly included in the numpy array!

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([998, 999, 1000, 1001])

filter_arr = arr > 999

newarr = arr[filter_arr]

print(filter_arr)
print(newarr)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_filter.asp

Comment: This approach is faster but it does not print the index which match the condition. You'll still to do element-wise comparisons which will increase the complexity.

Comment: Indeed, I missed the part to find the indexes and not the elements them-self. You could use indexOf, but I'm not sur it is the best way to find the indexes...

Comment: I'ld go with numpy.where then

Comment: I was testing on my machine and it seems that `np.where` gives more consistent time results but sometimes `np.argwhere` is faster.

Comment: as mentioned I need indices not elements, using np.where on filter_arr might be a little faster but it will be slower in overall